# typescript overload ignores second option

Tags: typescript

I have the following method signature:

```js
class Foo<T> {
  sanitize (value: unknown): returnPrimitive<T>
  sanitize (value: unknown[]): returnPrimitive<T>[]
  sanitize (value: unknown | unknown[]): returnPrimitive<T> | returnPrimitive<T>[] {
    // ...
  }
}

type returnPrimitive<T> =
    T extends String ? string
  : T extends Number ? number
  : T extends Boolean ? boolean
  : T
```

No matter how I call this method, IntelliSense never figures out that it should return an array:

```js
const a = new Foo<Number>().sanitize('5') // returns number
const b = new Foo<Number>().sanitize(['5']) // returns number instead of number[]
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this on typescript playground. I suspected that this was happening because `unknown` *includes* `unknown[]`

However, if I turn the more precise definition around, I get the behavior you want:

```js
class Foo<T> {
  sanitize (value: unknown[]): returnPrimitive<T>[]
  sanitize (value: unknown): returnPrimitive<T>
  sanitize (value: unknown | unknown[]): returnPrimitive<T> | returnPrimitive<T>[] {
    return 'foo' as any;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the first thing I tried. Using the example from here it indeed solves the problem. For my actual code (which is more or less the same) it doesn't work. It doesn't even recognize that there is +1 overload (as it does with my not working example here). It's just completely ignored. Unfortunately not an issue which was fixed by restarting VSCode...

Comment: @Fuzzyma best suggestion I can give to try to alter your code to get to a point where it _does_ reproduce. It's hard to imagine what could be different about your case.

Comment: This is ridiculous. I will continue looking. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it works for you

```js
class Foo<T> {
  sanitize<S extends any | any[]>(value: S): Check<T, S> {
    return 'foo' as any
  }
}

type Check<T, S> = S extends any[]
  ? returnPrimitive<T>[]
  : returnPrimitive<T>

type returnPrimitive<T> = T extends String
  ? string
  : T extends Number
  ? number
  : T extends Boolean
  ? boolean
  : T

const a = new Foo<Number>().sanitize('5') // number
const b = new Foo<Number>().sanitize(['5']) // number[]
```